# move array field to another field in another array editing it

Tags: arrays, bash, directory

This script should store folders in a dir in fvar2 as `folder1/ folder2/ folder3/`
and then echo in fvar1 as `folder1 folder2 folder3` using "sed" command.
In the end it should echo all dirs in the new array fvar1

This is the error

```
./test.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token ``echo "${fvar2[svar3]}" | sed 's#/##g'`'
./test.sh: line 18: `{fvar1[svar4]}=(`echo "${fvar2[svar3]}" | sed 's#/##g'`)'
```

And This is the Script

```
#!/bin/bash

fvar2=(*/)
svar3=0
svar4=0

while true
do

{fvar1[svar4]}=(`echo "${fvar2[svar3]}" | sed 's#/##g'`)
svar3=`expr $svar3 + 1`
svar4=`expr $svar4 + 1`
echo "${fvar1[svar4]}"

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper bash way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# When using globs, always use either nullglob or failglob
shopt -s nullglob

# define your array fvar2
declare -a fvar2=( */ )

# Remove the trailing slash in each field of fvar2, and make an array fvar1 of it
declare -a fvar1=( "${fvar2[@]%/}" )

# Print each field of array fvar2, one field per line
printf '%s\n' "${fvar1[@]}"
```

This is 100% safe and bullet-proof regarding file names with funny symbols (spaces, newlines, etc.).

---

Now let me extend this answer a little bit, to show you how you would build an array from another one with more involved processing. Usually, simple processings can be done using [Shell Parameter Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). But if this is not enough, e.g., you want to only keep the substrings of length 4 starting at offset 7 of each field in an array `array1`. The solution

```
declare -a array2=( "${array1[@]:7:4}" )
```

will not work, since this will take the fields 7 to 11 of `array1`, as you will read in the link I gave above. Here, you really need to loop through `array1`, do the processing, and push this on `array2`. This is how you'll do:

```
# empty and initialize array2
declare -a array2=()
for i in "${array2[@]}"; do
    array2+=( "${i:7:4}" )
done
```

The `+=` operator will concatenate the arrays of the lhs and rhs, putting the result on the array of the lhs. Look:

```
$ declare -a array1=( banana{00..10}gorilla )
$ printf '%s\n' "${array2[@]}"
banana00gorilla
banana01gorilla
banana02gorilla
banana03gorilla
banana04gorilla
banana05gorilla
banana06gorilla
banana07gorilla
banana08gorilla
banana09gorilla
banana10gorilla
$ declare -a array2=()
$ for i in "${array1[@]}"; do array2+=( "${i:7:4}" ); done
$ printf '%s\n' "${array2[@]}"
0gor
1gor
2gor
3gor
4gor
5gor
6gor
7gor
8gor
9gor
0gor
```

---

### Request to explain `shopt -s nullglob`

When using bash's globs, always use `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob` is you really want a robust script. Why? Look:

```
$ shopt -u nullglob failglob # unsetting nullglob and failglob
$ echo there_are_no_files_matching_this_glob_in_this_directory_*
there_are_no_files_matching_this_glob_in_this_directory_*
```

As you have seen, when nullglob and failglob are unset, if there are no globbing matches, bash will expand the glob to itself, verbatim. This can lead to terrible stuff inside scripts, e.g., if you want to rename all files that end with `.txt` by prepending `banana` to them, you'd do this... but what if there are no files ending with `.txt` in the directory?

```
$ shopt -u nullglob failglob
$ for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "banana$i.txt"; done
mv: cannot stat `*.txt': No such file or directory
$ # oh dear :(
```

Yes, *oh dear `:(`* because you've run a command without controlling its arguments... this can potentially be dangerous.

Now, if you turn `nullglob` on, and if there are no matches, the glob will expand to nothing! `:)`. Look:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob; shopt -u failglob
$ for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "banana$i.txt"; done
$ # Oh... nothing happened, great!
```

Or, if you turn `failglob` on, and if there are no matches, bash will raise an error:

```
$ shopt -s failglob; shopt -u nullglob
$ for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "banana$i.txt"; done
bash: no match: *.txt
$ # Good :)
```

and the loop never gets executed (which is good! you don't want to run commands without controlling their arguments).

What if you turn both on?

```
$ shopt -s nullglob failglob
$ for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "banana$i.txt"; done
bash: no match: *.txt
$ # Good :)
```

oh, `failglob` seems to win.

In your case, I guess you want your array to be truly empty if there are no directories. Look:

```
$ # I'm in a directory with no subdirs
$ # I'm unsetting nullglob and failglob
$ shopt -u nullglob failglob
$ array=( */ )
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="*/")
$ # Oh dear, my array contains */ verbatim
$ # now, let's set nullglob
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ array=( */ )
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='()'
$ # Now array is truly empty! :)
$ # How about failglob?
$ shopt -u nullglob; shopt -s failglob
$ # You'll see the failure in $? look:
$ echo $?
0
$ # all is good about $?
$ array=( */ )
bash: no match: */
$ echo $?
1
$ # :)
```

But with `failglob` your array will not be reset:

```
$ declare -a array=( some junk in my array )
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="some" [1]="junk" [2]="in" [3]="my" [4]="array")'
$ shopt -u nullglob; shopt -s failglob
$ array=( */ )
bash: no match: */
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="some" [1]="junk" [2]="in" [3]="my" [4]="array")'
$ # Ok, got it! :)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `shopt -s nullglob` does?

Comment: Thank You! I'm working with bash since a little time and i want to lear everything that could be usefull.